# How to Open decompiled apk file with eclipse?

Tags: file, apk, extract

I have decompiled apk file using apktool. It creates res folder, smali folder, AndroidManifest.xml and apktool.yml. I am not an expert with the smali files that is why I decompiled the classes.dex from the apk file using dex2jar then used jd-gui to get the java source code. Now, I don't how to load them in Eclipse.

Comment: In Eclipse, File | Open | Browse to the java source code ?

Answer (score 0):

Decompiled code is not equals source code. You can only view code in eclipse File - Open.
You can't  compile that code again.